# Why won't XCode allow me to see the preprocessor output?

Tags: xcode

I have some pre-processor macros I'm trying to debug, but the option to view the output of the pre-processor is disabled.  Why?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only files which are compiler inputs can be preprocessed.

Preprocess a source code file which includes this header.